# Content Plugin 'loads' multiple times on Category Page

Tags: development, plugin, fix-my-code

I have a plugin where I am trying to instantiate a new class but every time the plugin was enabled, the page kept dying saying the object already exists. Upon investigating, I found out that it only happens in Category Page and not Article page.

So I removed everything in the code and had the following code:

```
class plgContentFoobar extends JPlugin
{
  public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
  {
    echo 1;
  }
}
```

On the Article page, it just outputs once as expected but on a category page; it outputs 15 times. Is there anything I need to be aware which is causing this on the category pages?

Comment: How many articles are displayed on the category page?

Comment: @Lodder 14 articles on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so the function executes 15 times and you have 14 articles assigned to a category.

If you open the following file:

> components\com_content\views\article\view.html.php

you see the event dispatched on line **161**:

```
$dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.article', &$item, &$item->params, $offset));
```

Then in this file:

> components\com_content\views\category\view.html.php

You also see it dispatched on line **106**:

```
$dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.category', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
```

---

As you are on the category view and have 14 articles assigned to the category, the `onContentPrepare` is dispatched **14** times and then **once** again from the category view.

Comment: That explains it. Marking it as an answer but is it possible to dispatch the onContentPrepare just once? What I am trying to do requires the code to run just once otherwise it fails which explains why it worked on Article Page and not Category page.

Comment: It would be best to create a new question, showing the full code your using

Answer (score 1):

Contnet plugins fire on each content portion - each module, each article on a blog page and so on.
If you want to replace something unsing one run of a plugin you should use a system plugin and onAfterRender

```
    function onAfterRender() {
            $body = JResponse::getBody();
            // replace what you need in the $body
            JResponse::setBody($body);
   }
```

Comment: This is the appropriate answer for what I wanted to do but for the question I asked, I will keep the 'Marked Answer' as the one above.